# Why is Math.max(timeLeft/1000, 0) returning 0 as maximum value?

Tags: javascript, date, local-storage

I am trying to understand `Math.max(timeLeft/1000,0);` returning its maximum value as `0`. I did a lot of research as a noob. I read the [w3schools's](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp) tutorial about Math and all its methods. However the value returning `0` is really confusing me. The full code is below.

```
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var dis = document.getElementById("display");
var finishTime;
var timerLength = 10;
var timeoutID;
dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + timerLength;
if(localStorage.getItem('myTime')){
    Update();
}
start.onclick = function () {
    localStorage.setItem('myTime', ((new Date()).getTime() + timerLength * 1000));
    if (timeoutID != undefined) window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    Update();
}

function Update() {
    finishTime = localStorage.getItem('myTime');
    var timeLeft = (finishTime - new Date());
    dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + Math.max(timeLeft/1000,0);
    timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Update, 100);
}
```

Also why is `window.setTimeout(Update, 100);` behaving as `setInterval` in this code?

The full working code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5f5qexre/1/)

Note: I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100767/keeping-a-timer-consistent-after-multiple-refreshes-in-javascript) and I'm trying to understand how `localstorage` is working with the `date` function.

Another note: There is nothing wrong with the code above. It is working as it should. I am just trying to understand a certain piece of code, which is really confusing. I now understand why it is returning as `0`.

Comment: `finishTime - new Date()` is likely returning a negative number. `0` is larger than any negative number.

Comment: Please update the question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Also, ask **one** question/question, not two.

Comment: You need to learn how to use debugger to debug the code. Set some breakpoints, log the value of `timeLeft` and other vars, it shouldn't be hard to find out the reason.

Comment: new Date() is a object returning a current date. To test I used this code (new Date()).getTime(); It is returning current date and time in milliseconds.

Comment: Question : can you tell us what is the output of `localStorage.getItem('myTime')` ? Remark : `aDate - new Date()` is likely to return a negative integer since `new Date` is *now*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Since `Update` calls `window.setTimeout` again, one might argue that it does. At least I guess that's the behavior the OP is referring to.

Comment: *"new Date() is a object returning a current date."* Yes, that is correct. If `finishTime` is a value representing a date in the *past*, then `new Date()` will return a larger value. A small value minus a large value results in a negative number. What `Math.max` does is very simply. If you get `0` as result, then the other number must be `<= 0`. It's not that complicated.

Comment: @BryanChen Yes I did it a lot. If you run (finishTime - new Date()) on onclick event it should return a positive number as timerlength but it is returning negative number.

Comment: I tried the jsfiddle, and it seems to work correctly: `timeLeft` is positive for 10 seconds until it goes negative and the visible timer stops at 0. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: @procrastinator Thanks I get that. I see that the finishTime is decreasing from the positive integer 10. So whenever I click on button, the value is updated.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks Now I get that. Even after refresh the finishTime is same as before when we set the value on onclick event. And it doesn't change until we click the button again. Thanks again. Also can you explain why setTimeout is behaving like setInterval?

Comment: Again : can you tell us what is the output of `localStorage.getItem('myTime')` ? Copy-paste please ;-)

Comment: @procrastinator myTime: 1483266244327 in LocalStorage in console. It returns the current time when we first click on the button and keep going towards negative. Why this is going to negative too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.max(timeLeft/1000, 0)` return 0 when timeLeft is non-positive number.

`window.setTimeout(Update, 100)` is behaving as `setInterval` is that it call itself in loop every 100 just as the `setInterval`.

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to find that loop that make the setTimeout is executed evertime. Can you point it in code please.

Comment: the setTimeout is in the Update function. Update execute every 100 in your code. So does the setTimeout.

Answer (score 3):

`timeLeft` is negative, so 0 is the max value.

Comment: Yes I get it now. how the timeLeft is returning negative value. Also could you please explain why the setTimeout is behaving like setInterval ?

Comment: setTimeout vs. setInterval has been discussed a few times already, e.g. here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Math.max` does not always returns zero, otherwise you would always see "0" in the display span. It returns zero only when `new Date()` becomes greater than `finishTime` (after `timerLength * 1000` ms = 10 * 1000 ms = 10 s).

About `setTimeout`, considering the following code, `f` calls `setTimeout`, which calls `f` after 1 sec, which calls `setTimeout`, and so on :

```
function f () {
  setTimeout(f, 1000);
}
```

The result is similar to `setInterval` but not exactly the same. Read the following article to know why (author : jQuery's father himself) : http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/.

```js
var start = document.getElementById("start");
var dis = document.getElementById("display");
var finishTime;
var timerLength = 10;
var timeoutID;
var fakeStorage = (new Date()).getTime() + timerLength * 1000;
dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + timerLength;
if(fakeStorage){
  Update();
}
start.onclick = function () {
  fakeStorage = ((new Date()).getTime() + timerLength * 1000);
  if (timeoutID != undefined) window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  Update();
}

function Update() {
  finishTime = fakeStorage;
  var timeLeft = (finishTime - new Date());
  dis.innerHTML = "Time Left: " + Math.max(timeLeft/1000,0);
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(Update, 100);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="start">start</button>
<span id="display"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for defining setTimeout inside a function. It was in more detail.